# Where can I set a check constraint in SSMS Table Designer Mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

So here I have a table:

[image]

What I want is to add a check constraint for the column SessionState in the above designer mode so it can work like a enum. But unfortunately, I can't find the place where I can do that.

I tried right also "`right click -> script table as-> create table`" but here I can't make a not null check:

[image]

Comment: You should provide your actual code.

Comment: @DT what do you mean my actuall code. I didn't created my table writing code i just clickt right click new table and added the columns in designer mode. where can I see the right code?

Comment: Right click the column and choose "check constraints" - I recommend against using the visual designers though

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on the `SessionState` and Select `Check Constraints...`
Then add your constraint.

[image]

Or Select `dbo.Table > Constraints > New Constraints... > Expression (under General)` and then enter your expression.

```
([SessionState]='Unknown' OR [SessionState]='Useless' OR [SessionState]='Useful')
```

[image]
*Img Full Size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvgJX.png*

[image]
*Img Full Size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMsEK.png*

Or simply enter this code

```
Alter Table TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint_name Check (SessionState IN ('Useful', 'Useless', 'Unknown'))
```

**Updated**

(Backup all data)

Run this query and get all null & unsupported values.
Then, change them (change `SessionState` values).

```
Select * from [Session] WHERE SessionState IS NULL OR SessionState NOT IN ('Useful', 'Useless', 'Unknown')
```

To change, use this queries...

```
UPDATE [Session] SET SessionState='Unknown' WHERE SessionState IS NULL

UPDATE [Session] SET SessionState='Unknown' WHERE SessionState NOT IN ('Useful', 'Useless', 'Unknown')
```

Do the first step again after changing the values.

Then run these queries...

```
Alter Table Session
ALTER COLUMN SessionState nchar(40) NOT NULL

Alter Table Session
ADD CONSTRAINT Constraint_name Check (SessionState IN ('Useful', 'Useless', 'Unknown'))
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/TGW65894

For additional information, refer this video: https://youtu.be/9Zj5ODhv0b0

Comment: i tried it. But the problem is that i do not want to allow nulls and i settet "default value or binding" to 'Created' and when I want to save it I get this error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'SessionState', table 'SessionRatingDB.dbo.Tmp_Session'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: i fixed it but now the error occus: 'Session' table
- Unable to add constraint 'CK_SessionState'.  
The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_SessionState". The conflict occurred in database "SessionRatingDB", table "dbo.Session", column 'SessionState'.

Comment: Check whether your SessionState column has null or other values that do not fit with your constraint. For example, let say your SessionState column has 'test' value. You have to modify or delete that row in order to add the constraint.

Comment: actually no but can it be that "Created blank blank blank" is not the same as "Created" because when set the value to Created it automatically sets the blanks

Comment: @Lebron11 check answer now.